# Format HTML report generated using Python

Tags: python, html, reporting

I am trying to generate an HTML report of a few pandas data frames and plotly charts.
I am using the below code to export a table or graph in HTML.

```
with open("Result1.html", 'a') as f:
    f.write('<center>'
            +'<h1> Data Discovery </h1><br><hr>'
            +'<h2> Report - Descriptive Statistics</h2>' 
            + dfd.to_html(border=2,justify="center")
            +'</center>') 
fig = px.scatter(df, x=row["Column_Name1"], y=row["Column_Name2"],width=800, height=400)
fig.update_layout(title='scatter plot ' + row["Column_Name1"] + ' Vs ' + row["Column_Name2"])
with open('Result1.html', 'a') as f:
    f.write(fig.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
```

It generates a required to report but I wanted to check if there is any way I can generate a formatted HTML report.

I need to generate a scatter plot for specific columns based on high correlation and then export it in html. For which I have written custom code. But it returns results in the plain HTML page, I wanted to see if there is any formatting option available when exporting the HTML report

Comment: I think pandas-profiling will help you - https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling

Comment: @BaliDataMan, Thanks for your reply. I tried this but I need to generate scatter plot for specific columns based on high correlation and then export it in excel. For which I have written custom code. But it return results in plan HTML page, I wanted to see if there is any formatting option available when export html report